# generic method to search for an LINQ entity based on its type

Tags: linq, generics

```
partial void UpdateDenomLimit(DenomLimit instance)
{
     var oldData = DataClassesDataContext.DenomLimits.Where(b => b.ID == instance.ID).First();

     //Code that logs the audit when instance and oldData is passed to it
     LogAudit(oldData, instance);

     //Code that updates the instance
     this.ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
}
```

Above is a method for updating an instance of DenomLimit in the database.
I am logging an audit of what changes are done to the entity. For that I get the previous state of the instance by the following code and it works fine:

```
     var oldData = DataClassesDataContext.DenomLimits.Where(b => b.ID == instance.ID).First();
```

now I need a generic LINQ query which can fetch the oldData when three parameters are passed to it:
1. an instance of any type
2. A primary key column name
3. A value of primary key column for the passed instance.

...so that I can keep that code in the LogAudit and then do not need to fetch in every function.

A LINQ query which will possibly look like:

```
var oldData = DataClassesDataContext.GetTable<instance>().Where("b => b." + colName + " == @0", new object[] { id }).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The full namespace is used here to indicate the namespace that it came from to make it easier to incorporate into your code.

```
    public T GetFirstOrDefault<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> func) where T : class
    {
        DataClassesDataContext.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(func);
        // For EF 4.1 Code First
        //return (ctx as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(func);
        // or
        //return ctx.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(func);
    }
```

In this case using an Expression of a Func allows EF to figure out what data you are looking for.
Here is an example of how it would be used:

```
var a1 = GetFirstOrDefault<DenomLimits>(p => p.ID == oldData.ID);
var a2 = GetFirstOrDefault<DenomLimits>(p => p.OtherID == 5);
```